# Django: Where is the first place you can query auth user model for the ADMINS Setting?

Tags: django

I am trying to set up the email & ADMINS setting and would like to query the User model to get the email addresses & other email credentials so i don't have to give that info to everybody on git hub.  If i put the following in the end of my settings file (after database is defined):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u1 = User.objects.get(pk__exact=1)
ADMINS = ((u1.username, u1.email))
print ADMINS
```

I get a successful query and the sever launches, but when i try to launch the app i get various errors due to missing settings depending where in the settings file i put the above code.

From this i gather that you can not query a database in the settings file so where can i put this code so that it populates the ADMINS settings and email settings variables when the server starts up?

Comment: I would suggest a raw SQL query for this thing. You can extract the name of the table from the app and model. The ADMINS in settings.py and the superusers mean different things (the first are expected to manage the site, while the others to manage the content), so it's unnatural to expect that such behaviour is easily achievable.

Comment: the raw SQL does not work either.  I'm guessing that the user exposed settings are loaded before dome other django setup happens and any query in settings prevents those things from happening...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not use django models in `settings.py`,

Generally, after `settings.py` loads, django knows what the database config is.

A more idiomatic practice is add some piece of code **at the end of settings.py**:

```
from local_settings import *
```

or just overwrite `ADMINS` to the namespace, hardcode `ADMINS = (('admin', 'admin@example.com'))` in local_settings,

```
from local_settings import ADMINS
```

As you do not want to expose the information to github, add `local_settings.py` to your `.gitignore`.

As @DJV said," ADMINS in settings.py and the superusers mean different things (the first are expected to manage the site, while the others to manage the content)", I do not think ADMINS is so important.

Comment: I am using ADMINS mainly for it's automated email on 500 error so I want an easy way to query the User model for the ADMINS instead of hard coding it.  I have come up with a solution that seems to be working well and am about to post it as an answer.  What do you think?

Comment: although this answer has useful information it does not provide a solution to question: Where is the first place you can query auth user model for the ADMINS Setting? The key point being that i NEED to query the user model to populate the ADMINS setting.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this code to run when the server is spun up not at each request and this solution seems to be doing just that.  I don't want to hard code the ADMINS because i like the idea of using django's admin to manage users and since i am pulling the username and email from the database i don't have to worry about exposing the user's info info in the code.

I created a file called admins.py in my application and in  **init**.py imported that file to execute the code.  Now when a user is_superuser their info will be added to ADMINS automatically.

myapp.core.**init**.py

```
from myapp.core.admins import *
```

myapp.core.admins.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

#admins setup: These users will get 500 error emails
admins = User.objects.filter(is_superuser__exact=True)
settings.ADMINS = []
for u in admins:
    settings.ADMINS.append((u.username, u.email))

#send test email
if settings.SEND_TEST_EMAIL:
    mail_admins('SEVER HAS BEEN STARTED', 'The server has been started @ '+settings.SITE_IP, fail_silently=False)
```

UPDATE: There is an issue with the above solution. I had to rebuild my database and when i ran syncdb it fails due to a missing user model. I tried moving the import to models.py init but still no luck. Where is the first safe point of entry?? Do i have to create an admins model or create user profiles to extend auth/user and add an is_admin field? –